# Jquery, Why last function in script not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

please tell me where I am making a mistake in this code, all functions except the last one are being processed, I can not understand why. The first 3 functions correctly submit the form and receive a response, the latter also submits the form, but for some reason the response opens on a new page.

```
jQuery(document).submit(function(e){
    var form = jQuery(e.target);
    
    var id = form.attr("action");
    var ret = id.replace('/changepswd/','');
    
    if(form.is("#changepswd")){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: form.attr("action"), 
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                document.getElementById("changepswdbtn" + ret).value  = '';
                alertTimeout(data,1000);
            }
        });
    }
});

jQuery(document).submit(function(n){
    var form = jQuery(n.target);
    
    var id = form.attr("action");
    var ret = id.replace('/changeemailpass/','');
    
    if(form.is("#changeemailpass")){
        n.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: form.attr("action"), 
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                document.getElementById("changeemailpassbtn" + ret).value  = '';
                alertTimeout(data,1000);
            }
        });
    }
});

jQuery(document).submit(function(q){
    var form = jQuery(q.target);
    
    var id = form.attr("action");
    var ret = id.replace('/changename/','');
    
    var btns = document.getElementById("changenamebtn" + ret).value;
    
    if(form.is("#changename")){
        q.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: form.attr("action"), 
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data == "Имя Успешно Изменено!"){
                    document.getElementById("changenamelbl" + ret).innerText = btns;
                    document.getElementById("changenamebtn" + ret).value  = '';
                    alertTimeout(data,1000);
                }
                else{
                    alertTimeout(data,1000);    
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

jQuery(document).submit(function(o){
    var form = jQuery(o.target);
    
    var id = form.attr("action");
    var ret = id.replace('/changeemail/','');
    
    var btns = document.getElementById("changeemailbtn" + ret).value;
    
    if(form.is("#changeemail")){
        o.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: form.attr("action"), 
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data == "Email Успешно Изменен!"){
                    document.getElementById("changeemaillbl" + ret).innerText = btns;
                    document.getElementById("changeemailbtn" + ret).value  = '';
                    alertTimeout(data,1000);
                }
                else{
                    alertTimeout(data,1000);    
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You only prevent default on a match, so if your form is not `#changeemail` then it won't prevent the default and the *button* will submit the form and reload the page.   Without more details (eg the form/button html) it's not possible to provide more information.  But you might like to `o.,preventDefault()` *outside* the `if`